# Google Search bar script not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-search-api

Hi I am trying to get a google search bar script to work on my site.

When you're first on the page it looks like a magnifying glass in the corner (like so)
[image: magnify]

Then once you click on the magnify glass it goes into this
[image: searchbar]

For some reason the search bar is only working on the home page of the website (no lower level pages) and its not exactly searching our site.

The code I have is as follows:

Search Script

```
   <div class="hide" >
    <script>
    (function() {
        var cx = '000937597557157891839:ruyewipqtri';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
       })();
       </script>
        <gcse:searchbox-only gname="search-box"   resultsUrl="//test.iowalum.com/search-results/"></gcse:searchbox-only>
        </div>
```

I keep attempting to get the resultsURL changed since we are not on our test server anymore it should just be iowalum.com but whenever I change that URL it breaks the site.

The Search Results Script I have is:

```
    <script>
    (function() {
     var cx = '000937597557157891839:ruyewipqtri';
     var gcse = document.createElement('script');
     gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
     gcse.async = true;
     gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
     })();
     </script>
     <style>
     .gsc-control-wrapper-cse {
      padding:0;    
      }
     .gsc-results-wrapper-nooverlay {
      padding: 0;
      }
      .gsc-wrapper {
       padding: 0;
      }
      </style>
      <gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Lastly the actual search part or include on each of the web pages is:

```
     <li class="search-module" search min-z-index-toggle="0">

           <!-- <div class="input-container">
            <input search-input class="search-input" aria-label="find   something...">
             <div class="placeholder-SHIV">find something...</div>
           </div> -->

            <div class="input-container">
             <cfinclude template = "//_includes/search.cfm">
             <div class="placeholder-SHIV">find something...</div>
            </div>

            <a search-button class="button icon svg-container">
            <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><use   xlink:href="#svg-search"></svg>
            </a>
            </li>




Here I have the same issue as with the search URL whenever I attempt
to change the path the site breaks. I think this might be why it's 
only working on the home page though since it is not the full path
 and others are sub pages?
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: I got it to search my site and work on more page by changing the header part to ../_includes/search.cfm however Its only working on about half the pages now?